# What type of a modem/router/switch for LAN party where no internet access is needed?

Tags: router, lan, modem, switch

What type of a "box" would be suitable for only LAN connections?

Im about to have a nice little LAN party with 6 people coming in and we dont need the internet, just some local "switch". I started reading about Netgear switches such as "Netgear GS108GE" but then I noticed that you need a "router" or internet connection for these to work. Nowhere is it ever said that a box could be used strictly for LAN.

What type of a box do I need to simply have a local area network between 7 machines?

No matter what I google I cant get a clear answer to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: all routers/switches are usable as LAN only because computers connect to the router via LAN, and the router connects to the ISP via another "LAN". Internet is only needed when one wants to surf the internet

Comment: I think that your confusion is in how you interpret the statement about requiring a router. The intended meaning is that _you need a "router" or internet connection for these to **provide internet connectivity**_. The Netgear GS108 is a great switch all round.

Comment: What's the problem with just using any router or switch? You won't see any benefit by removing internet capabilities.

Answer (score 7):

Technically, **a basic Ethernet switch** is enough for LAN communications. All you really *need* is the ability to exchange packets, and switches & hubs do exactly that; and they most certainly work without an Internet connection.

*(Don't get a hub, though. While it also relays L2 frames just like a switch would, hubs will give you awful performance at best – Gigabit Ethernet requires a switched network.)*

The *primary* job of a router is to connect networks together (e.g. Internet and a LAN, or just two LANs), but you only have one isolated network so there's nothing to route. Likewise, a modem bridges between different signal types, e.g. Ethernet to ADSL – if your network is 100% Ethernet, you don't need a modem.

---

But one concern is **IP address assignment** – if you want the convenience of DHCP (instead of telling everyone to manually configure IPv4 addresses), then you *will* need a DHCP server *somewhere* in your LAN. Likewise with IPv6 and SLAAC.

On the one hand, it doesn't have to be an actual router – you could hook up a RasPi or any old Linux system, then set up dnsmasq (or dhcpd + radvd) on it. On the other hand, home routers already come with the same preconfigured.

Most home "routers", after all, are N-in-one devices: you get a 4-port switch internally connected to a CPU performing routing tasks. So even if you don't have any Internet connection, you can still use a home "router" or "modem" as an average switch + WiFi AP + DHCP server.

---

Finally, should you need to *extend* the LAN (e.g. if you ran out of Ethernet ports), then a switch will be 100% enough for that. Best not to try to chain multiple routers.

Comment: Assuming the OP is running Windows computers, he doesn't need a DHCP server because with Automatic Private IP Addressing (APIPA) *"[a Windows computer can assign itself an Internet Protocol (IP) address](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/220874/how-to-use-automatic-tcp-ip-addressing-without-a-dhcp-server) in the event that a DHCP server is not available or does not exist on the network."* Though I've *never* used this feature and have always suspected it worked about as well as PnP did in 2000...